# 1and1 ssh - connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I'm having troubles connecting through SSH to my 1&1 account.
When I try to connect with command

```
userXXX@host -p22 -vv
```

I have the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mySite.com [ip_here] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ip_here port 22: Connection refused
```

Moreover, once I try to connect through SSH and it fails, even the HTTP access is dead, I cannot access the website through explorer anymore :/

please help ><

I'm running ubuntu 11.10

EDIT: don't know if it can help, here's the .htaccess of the 1and1 server

```
Options +Indexes
Satisfy any
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 212.227.X.X
Deny from all
RemoveType .html .gif
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /logs"
AuthUserFile /kunden/homepages/43/d376072470/htpasswd
Require user "user_here"
```

and sftp.log:

```
Mar 26 09:21:24 193.251.X USER_HERE Connection from 193.251.X port 51809
Mar 26 09:21:30 193.251.X USER_HERE Failed password for USER_HERE from 193.251.X port 51809 ssh2
Mar 26 09:23:39 193.251.X USER_HERE Failed password for USER_HERE from 193.251.X port 51809 ssh2
Mar 26 09:23:41 193.251.X USER_HERE Failed password for USER_HERE from 193.251.X port 51809 ssh2
Mar 26 09:23:45 193.251.X USER_HERE Failed password for USER_HERE from 193.251.X port 51809 ssh2
Mar 26 09:23:57 193.251.X USER_HERE Failed password for USER_HERE from 193.251.X port 51809 ssh2
Mar 26 10:53:36 212.227.X tmp64459736-3228 Connection from 212.227.X port 23275
Mar 26 10:53:36 212.227.X tmp64459736-3228 Accepted password for tmp64459736-3228 from 212.227.X port 23275 ssh2
Mar 26 11:53:37 212.227.X tmp64459736-3228 Connection closed by 212.227.X
Mar 26 18:58:17 212.227.X tmp64459736-5363 Connection from 212.227.X port 23353
Mar 26 18:58:17 212.227.X tmp64459736-5363 Accepted password for tmp64459736-5363 from 212.227.X port 23353 ssh2
Mar 26 19:53:36 212.227.X tmp64459736-8525 Connection from 212.227.X port 5166
Mar 26 19:53:36 212.227.X tmp64459736-8525 Accepted password for tmp64459736-8525 from 212.227.X port 5166 ssh2
Mar 26 19:58:17 212.227.X tmp64459736-5363 Connection closed by 212.227.X
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if it is an old question, the answer can be useful. I just had the same problem today.

The problem comes from 1and1 that blocks the IP address after some attempts (2-3 I think) to connect with SSH with the wrong password or the wrong username. The site is blocked in SSH as well as HTTP(S).

The solution is to contact them to unblock the address IP and to make sure that password and the username are correct before connecting with SSH.

Comment: I just had this same problem, it's currently after 2 failed sets of 3 attempts.

Comment: Is there an easier way than just calling them, i hate this so much!

Comment: Looks like, based on [follow-up comment on this blog post](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2006/03/23/banned-from-my-own-site/), that at least other causes for bans are temporary, but I'm trying email support since I don't have time to sit on hold.  Would be easier if SSH key login was supported, then I wouldn't be able to goof up the password... (and I'm letting them know as much)

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your router and, unless you have a fixed IP address (which most people don't) you will get a new IP address and 1&1 won't know it's you.